# add kotlin.native package to android studio project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to use a class (BitSet) form the `kotlin.native` package (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native/-bit-set/)

Android Studio adds an import from java.util.* witch is not equivalent to BitSet from kotlin.native, I cannot for example get the property lastTrueIndex from java.util.BitSet

How can I add the kotlin.native package to my project ?